# Convert 32-bit signed integer to 64-bit integer while preserving the exact bits

Tags: vb.net, types, type-conversion

I have a 32-bit value that is stored in the VB.Net type Integer (i.e. Int32.)  I am only interested in the bits - not the numerical value.  Sometimes the 32nd bit is a one which is interpreted as a negative number.  My goal is to reverse the actual bits.  My original data is encoded into bits right-to-left (LSB right-most) and is read back in left-to-right (MSB left-most.) I am adapting someone else's code and design. One thought I had was maybe to convert to a long temporarily but I don't know how to do that and preserve the 32nd bit correctly.

```
Public Shared Function ReverseBits32(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To 32 - 1
        result = result * 2 + n Mod 2

        n = n >> 1 'n Or 2
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: If you are interested in just the bit, why are you using signed integer?

Comment: I started with a sample application that originally worked with 8-bit values but was implemented using 32-bit integers.  That makes sense as that will have much higher performance.  My use requires 32-bit values.  It would greatly delay my project if I tried to convert the data types at this point.  I'll edit the question to more precisely explain my requirement.

Comment: It won't let me edit.  So I need a function to completely reverse the bits in a 32 bit signed integer.  I'm tripping over the 32nd bit when it is a one, thus making it a negative number.

Comment: So what you actually need is just a way to reverse the bits in a 32 bit integer, and that's what you're having trouble with?  You don't necessarily need to go to 64 bits at all, as long as there's some other way of reversing the 32 bits?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: @user339468 then, if you don't care about the integer value, negative value should be a problem since it properly represent the reverse bit that you are looking for. Maybe an example of why a 64bit is needed would help us understand.

Comment: Agreed.  It would be helpful if you could show us the code you've written so far and how the result is different from what you expect.  Without that, it's hard to help you since we don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: But, do you need to blindly reverse the bits (which would take `a BitArray, CopyTo()` a bool Array and `Array.Reverse()`) or you need to invert the bytes, to make transform it into the Big Endian representation of the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a method to reverse the bits of a byte you could apply it four times to the bytes of an integer. A little research finds [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

```
Module Module1

    Sub ShowBits(a As Integer)
        Dim aa = BitConverter.GetBytes(a)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", aa.Select(Function(b) Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c))))
    End Sub

    Function ReverseBits(b As Byte) As Byte
        ' From https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith32Bits
        Dim c = CULng(b)
        Return CByte((((c * &H802UL And &H22110UL) Or (c * &H8020UL And &H88440UL)) * &H10101UL >> 16) And &HFFUL)
    End Function

    Function ReverseBits(a As Integer) As Integer
        Dim bb = BitConverter.GetBytes(a)
        Dim cc(3) As Byte
        For i = 0 To 3
            cc(3 - i) = ReverseBits(bb(i))
        Next

        Return BitConverter.ToInt32(cc, 0)

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim y = -762334566
        ShowBits(y)
        y = ReverseBits(y)
        ShowBits(y)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Output from test value:

```
10011010 10110010 10001111 11010010
01001011 11110001 01001101 01011001
```

I used the "no 64-bit" method because it is written for a language where arithmetic overflow is ignored - the methods using 64-bit operations rely on that but it is not the default for VB.NET.

Comment: This will take me some time to puzzle out but I assume "CByte((((c * &H802UL And &H22110UL) Or (c * &H8020UL And &H88440UL)) * &H10101UL >> 16) And &HFFUL)" is handling the sign bit?  This looks promising.

Comment: A [Byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/byte-data-type) is unsigned. `BitConverter.GetBytes` gets the raw bytes without any interpretation. So the sign bit does not come into it :)